# How do I inject environment variables to Lambda running under sam local?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables, aws-sam

I am developing an aws lambda locally using AWS SAM.
I am trying to inject environment variables, with no success.
The Lambda code is:

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('INJECTED ENVIRONMENT:',JSON.stringify(process.env));
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': "booo"
    }
    return response;
};
```

The environment file **test.json** is:

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP1": "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP1",
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP2": "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP2",
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP3": "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP3"
  }
}
```

I am running the lambda. It runs ok, shows me the expected output, Except the env variables I tried defining.
**sam local invoke -e events/event.json -n test.json**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment variables file has a specific format it needs to adhere to that depends on the logical id of the lambda function you want to test:

Test.json:

```
{
  "LogicalIdOfLambdaHere":{
    "ENV_VAR_KEY": "value"
  }
}
```

Make sure the logical id matches the one defined in your sam template. Alternatively you can use `Parameters` instead of `parameters`.

**Note you also need to define the same variables in the actual SAM template.** This method is for overriding the values specified in the template and not for adding new ones not defined in the template. Variables are also case sensitive:)

Comment: I did try all of those options - I will verify again, in case I had a typo and update my question accordingly.

Comment: Note you also need to define the same variables in the actual SAM template. This method is for overriding the values specified in the template and not for adding new ones not defined in the template. Variables are also case sensitive:)

Comment: That did it, Can you add to the answer in bold the part where "Note you also need to define the same variables in the actual SAM template" -  so I can accept it

Comment: Done as requested